# How do you set default apps on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've clicked:
Windows Settings - System - Default apps - Choose default apps by file type - .pdf

But it shows only a few choices, including Windows store. How can I set the app to one that it is not in the list. Like Chrome, or an .exe of my choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click an pdf application -> Open with -> Choose another app -> Tick always use this app -> More apps -> Look for another app on this pc -> Browse to .exe -> Click the app you want to use for that file